# Proving that $\frac{\alpha+1}{e}(\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha-1})^{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}<\alpha-\frac{1}{6\alpha}$ for $\alpha>1$.

Tags: inequality

How can one prove that $\frac{\alpha+1}{e}(\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha-1})^{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}<\alpha-\frac{1}{6\alpha}$ for $\alpha>1$?

I ran across this inequality when reading [Cheng and Feast (1979)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2347200). I don't see how one could prove it. Any help would be appreciated.